# Issue with JSZip, Filesaver and saving multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, async-await, blob, jszip, filesaver.js

When using JSZip to generate a ZIP-file from multiple file-URLs, some users get empty ZIP-files. On macOS there does not seem to be a problem in various browsers, but on Windows the error occurs.

I suspect it to be related to promises, await and async.

This is my function to which I can pass a string as filename, and an array of URLs (located on the same server):

```
function saveToZip(filename, urls) {

    let zip = new JSZip();
    let count = 0;

    urls.forEach((url) => {
        const blobPromise = fetch(url).then(r => {
            if (r.status === 200) return r.blob()
            return Promise.reject(new Error(r.statusText))
        })
        let name = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'));
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        zip.file(name, blobPromise, {binary: true});
        count++;
        checkCount();
    });

    function checkCount(){
        if(count == urls.length){
            console.log('All files added to ZIP');
            createAndSaveZip()
        }
    }

    function createAndSaveZip(){
        zip.generateAsync({
            type: "blob",
            streamFiles: false
        }, function updateCallback(metadata) {
            console.log(Math.round(metadata.percent) + "%");
        }).then(function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, filename); // Filesaver.js
            console.log("Finished");
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, I first create a new JSZip, then loop through each URL in the array and add each to the ZIP-file.
Then a function checks if all URLs have been added. If so, generateAsync is used together with Filesaver to generate and save the ZIP-file.

You will notice the use of blob. Is this not working for browsers on Windows?
Is there something wrong in the way I have constructed the logic?

Comment: You're not waiting for the `blobPromise` to resolve before calling `checkCount`. I doubt you can even pass a promise to `zip.file`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. How would you construct the promises logic?

Comment: I'm not sure how `zip.file` needs to be called, but you'll want to use `blobPromise.then(blob => zip.file(name, blob, …))` and put these promise chains in an array, then call `Promise.all`. Don't use that `count++` thing